# How to include config file for variables in Lua

Tags: lua

In my lua script there are some variables I would like to put in a 'settings.conf' file so I can easily change variables without diving into the code.

In other languages they use 'include', but in Lua it seems different because it loads a [module](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require). I only need to load a config file for some parameters.
Which command should I use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to execute a Lua script from another script is to use [`dofile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-dofile), which takes a path to a file:

```
dofile"myconfig.lua"

dofile "/usr/share/myapp/config.lua"
```

The problem with `dofile` is that it can raise an error and abort the calling script. If you want to handle errors, such as the file not existing, syntax or execution errors, then use `pcall`:

```
local ok,e = pcall(dofile,"myconfig.lua")
if not ok then
  -- handle error; e has the error message
end
```

If you want finer control, then use `loadfile` followed by a function call:

```
local f,e = loadfile("myconfig.lua")
if f==nil then
  -- handle error; e has the error message
end
local ok,e = pcall(f)
if not ok then
  -- handle error; e has the error message
end
```

Comment: In the end your solution was better. I encountered some weird issues when using the other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

config.lua:

```
myconf = {
    param1 = "qwe";
    param2 = 7;
}
```

main program:

```
package.path = '*.lua;' .. package.path
require "config"
print("config param1 = " .. myconf.param1 .. "\n")
```

this works well in most cases.

Comment: except when you want to write a new configuration to the file.

Comment: @hjpotter92, do you mean if I overwrite this file that the configuration won't update? My apologies for my confusion, but I don't understand your statement completely.